# Order of event listeners

Tags: dart

Is there a way to manually order the execution of event listeners for the same element?

For example
If I have two methods that has onClick() listeners.

```
void A(Element el) {
   el.onClick((event) => model.get("inside"));
}

void B(Element el) {
   ....
   el.onClick((event) => expect(model.get("inside"), isNotNull));
   ....
}
```

Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to specify the order in which event listeners will fire. You could force the listener in `B` to wait on the listener in `A` by having a [`Completer`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.21.1/dart-async/Completer-class.html) that you call complete on after the listener in `A` finishes. Then you can have the listener in `B` wait on the completer.